# Generating a list of evenly distributed numbers from range

Tags: python, distribution

I have seen this question been asked before but I'm looking for an answer with a twist:

Consider I have a range like 1-100 and i want to generate a list, with a specific stepsize like: `numbers(1,100,5)`. This would return `[1,25,50,75,100]`. However, I would like it to return `[1,100,50,25,75]` or `[1,100,50,75,25]` Another example would be numbers(1,10,10) which would give me something similar to `[1,10,5,2,7,3,8,4,9]`.

Is this even possible to do? The reason for this would be to be able to render image sequences without going from frame 1 to frame 2 to frame 3 and so forth. Instead I want to render the first frame, the last frame, the middle frame, the middle of the middle frame until all frames are accounted for.

Comment: The lists you have don't match the stepsize jumps you requested and it makes your question very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is kind of underspecified, but this should help you get started.

```
def numbers(first, last, count):
    nums = [first, last]
    width = last - first
    while len(nums) < count:
        width /= 2
        stepper = first
        while stepper < last:
            rounded = round(stepper)
            if rounded not in nums:
                nums.append(rounded)
                if len(nums) == count:
                    break
            stepper += width
    return nums
```

Then:

```
>>> numbers(0, 100, 5)
[0, 100, 50, 25, 75]
>>> numbers(0, 10, 10)
[0, 10, 5, 2, 8, 1, 4, 6, 9, 3, 7]
>>> numbers(0, 50, 50)
[0, 50, 25, 12, 38, 6, 19, 31, 44, 3, 9, 16, 22, 28, 34, 41, 47, 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48, 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 15, 18, 21, 24, 26, 29, 32, 35, 37, 40, 43, 46]
```

The basic algorithm is as follows:

- Start with a list of `nums` containing the two endpoints
- Initialize `width` to the distance between the two endpoints
- Then, loop:

  - Halve `width`
  - Step through `first`, `first+width`, `first+2*width`, ..., `last-width`, `last`, and add whichever among those are not already in `nums` to `nums` (so, for `numbers(0, 100, 5)`, the first loop iteration will try 0, 50, and 100, and only add 50 since that wasn't already present; the second iteration will try 0, 25, 50, 75, and 100, and only add 25 and 75).
  - If we have enough numbers in `nums`, we're done
- Return `nums`

Comment: Awesome, thank you. sorry for being vague and getting my numbers wrong. Senshin understood better than myself what I wanted :)

Comment: I seem to be getting some strange result for som ranges, e.g: numbers(0,50,50) returns [0, 50, 25.0, 12.0, 24.0, 36.0, 48.0, 60.0, 6.0, 18.0, 30.0, 42.0, 54.0, 3.0, 9.0, 15.0, 21.0, 27.0, 33.0, 39.0, 45.0, 51.0, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 7.0, 8.0, 10.0, 11.0, 13.0, 14.0, 16.0, 17.0, 19.0, 20.0, 22.0, 23.0, 26.0, 28.0, 29.0, 31.0, 32.0, 34.0, 35.0, 37.0, 38.0, 40.0, 41.0, 43.0]. It's super close to being correct except for the 60 and 54. However, it's definitly close enough for me to work with so I will mark your answer as solved, thanks again!

Comment: @user2832718 Oops, my bad. The `stepper += width` line should've gone at the end of the inner `while` loop. Should behave more correctly now. Note that you'll probably want to implement some kind of error-checking (e.g. what if you call `numbers(0, 10, 20)`? You'll hit an infinite loop because there aren't 20 integers between 0 and 10) before using this.

Comment: Thanks a million times @senshin !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so your desired frames are kind of wierd, especially as the elements in the first example aren't evenly ranged, eg. 100-75=25, 75-50=25, 50-25=25 , **25-1=24**.

But, if we assume that you always want the start and end value in the frame and want the evenly spaced values pegged against the maximum value, we can do this:

```
def numbers(start,stop,step=1):
    frame = [start]+range(y,stop,(start-stop)/(step-1))
    return frame
```

The [`random`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module includes a [`shuffle()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) method that takes an array and shuffles it *in-place*.

Which means the function becomes:

```
from random import shuffle
def numbers(start,stop,step=1):
    frame = [start]+range(y,stop,(start-stop)/(step-1))
    shuffle(frame)
    return frame
```

Giving us the following test runs:

```
>>> numbers(1,100,5)
[100, 50, 75, 1, 25]
>>> numbers(1,10,10)
[1, 3, 10, 9, 6, 5, 8, 4, 7, 2]
```

---

Original (but wrong) answer

The [`random`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module includes a [`shuffle()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) method that takes an array and shuffles it *in-place*.

For example:

```
from random import shuffle
def numbers(start,stop,step=1):
    frame = range(start,stop,step)
    shuffle(frame)
    return frame
```

Then calling this function we get:

```
>>> numbers(1,100,25)
[1, 51, 26, 76]
>>> numbers(1,100,25)
[76, 26, 1, 51]
```

Note, that as per the [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) function, the `step` value is repeatedly added to `start` such that the final array is of the form `[start, start+1*step, start+2*step ... start + n*step]`, where `start+n*step` is less than `stop` while `start+(n+1)*step` is greater than `stop`.

Comment: I think that OP's desired output for e.g. `numbers(0, 100, 9)` (ignoring his off-by-one error) would be 0, 100, 50, 25, 75, 12.5, 37.5, 62.5, 87.5, if you see the pattern there - the values after the first two aren't random but rather are the median of [0, 100] → 50, and then the medians of [0, 50] → 25 and [50, 100] → 75, and then the medians of [0, 25] → 12.5; etc. (Except rounded to integers, I guess.)